# Monkey patch side effect

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to monkey patch a function retrieve_files which retrieves files from different directories,there are two calls to this function and for each call I need a different value, I am aware it is possible with mock using side effects but how can I acheive the same with Monkeypatch in Python

Comment: What do you mean by monkey patch vs mock? Mocking is for testing and you get a pre-specified deterministic result (most often a constant), while in operation you'll get what ever the method computes. 
Monky-Patching is for situations where you don't own the method/class and overwrite it 'illegally' the issue here is, that you now depend on the stability of the library. If the method is your own: Subclass+Overwrite, implement different methods for different purposes, or if you need a constant: Don't use a method.

Comment: @Cpt.Hook Yes you are correct it creates a deterministic result, you can use the mocking side effect to create new values each time a function is called for ex         mock = MagicMock(app.retrieve_files_name_size)
    mock.side_effect = [1,2]